# EF Core giving me error Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Tags' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

My project using DDD pattern,is built by .NET-core and EF core. Today, I meet a question is that when I add a tag entity to my database, then do saveChanges. But the program throw a Exception: "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Tags' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF"
And I am puzzled, also, I search the question on the stackoverfolw and google. I found some solution is that use the attribute 
`[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`, but is doesn't work for me. Here is my code below:

```
C#//Entity
public class Tags
{
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public TagUseCount TagUseCount { get; set; }
    public enum Operation
    {
        None = 0,
        Add = 2, 
        Update = 4
    }
}
```

The Function use in my Service Lawyer:

```
var tagEntity = new Tags { TagName = tag };
var tagId = await _tagRepository.Add(tagEntity);
```

The Add Function is Repository Lawyer:

```
public async Task<int> Add(Tags tags)
    {
        try
        {
            _unitOfWork.Add(tags);
            await _unitOfWork.CommitAsync();
            return tags.TagId;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(new EventId(), ex, "Error when add Tag!");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

UOW Add Method:

```
TEntity IUnitOfWork.Add<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
    {
        return base.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity).Entity;     
    }
```

`Version of EF core :"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0"`

ModelBuilder below:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tags>().ToTable("Tags")
            .HasKey(x => x.TagId);


modelBuilder.Entity<TagUseCount>().ToTable("TagUseCount")
            .HasKey(x => x.TagId);
modelBuilder.Entity<TagUseCount>().ToTable("TagUseCount")
           .HasOne(x => x.tags)
           .WithOne(q => q.tagUseCount);
```

I am crazy with it for a couple of days, Who can help me ?

Comment: Are you setting `TagId` somewhere in the code? Can we see the UOW `Add` method as well? Also what version of EF Core are you using? We probably can help, but need [mcve], i.e. something we can copy/paste and run.

Comment: I got the answer when I make a demo for my question, I solved it by comment the line in Tags.cs  `public TagUseCount TagUseCount { get; set; }` , but I don't know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer when I make a demo for my question, I solved it by comment the line in Tags.cs:

`public TagUseCount TagUseCount { get; set; }`

But I don't know why?

Here is my TagUseCount.cs below:

```
public class TagUseCount
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public int UseCount { get; set; }
    public Tags Tag { get; set; }
    public enum Operation
    {
        None = 0,
        Increment = 2,
        Decrement = 4
    }
}
```

Supply:
I research it and I found the error come from the code that I write in modelBuilder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tags>().ToTable("Tags")
        .HasKey(x => x.TagId);
modelBuilder.Entity<TagUseCount>().ToTable("TagUseCount")
        .HasKey(x => x.TagId);
modelBuilder.Entity<TagUseCount>().ToTable("TagUseCount")
       .HasOne(x => x.tags)
       .WithOne(q => q.tagUseCount);
```

When I change the code like that: it helps.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tags>().ToTable("Tags")
        .HasKey(x => x.TagId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Tags>()
        .HasOne(x => x.TagUseCount)
        .WithOne(y => y.Tags)
        .HasForeignKey(z => z.TagId)

modelBuilder.Entity<TagUseCount>().ToTable("TagUseCount")
        .HasKey(x => x.TagId);
```

Comment: I still don't understand why this resolves the issue. I am having the same problem with .NET Core 2.2.